# Relation between partially computable function and complex function

Tags: computability-theory, nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a partially computable function, is there an analytic complex function which is equal to it at every point of it's domain? Or under what condition does a partially computable function correspond to the restriction of an analytic complex function?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but could you define a C.e. function? Or at least write out the name, so I can search for a definition? Given the tags and the question, I guess it's the only reasonable mathematical definition I found when searching for c.e. function:
http://www.mathproservices.com/presentations/NewOrleans95/cefcndef.html

Comment: I meant if course: "I guess it's not the only reasonable mathematical definition"..

Comment: The questioner seems to be asking whether every computable function on $\mathbb{N}$ can be extended to a complex analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$. For example, computable functions can have crazy growth behavior, and perhaps this prevents such an extension.

Comment: In computability theory, c.e. is the usual abbreviation for *computably enumerable*, which is an adjective applied to sets: a set is computably enumerable if there is a computable procedure to enumerate its elements. The graph of a function is c.e. if and only if the function is computable, since on input $n$, one waits for $(n,k)$ to appear in the enumeration of the graph and at that point gives $k$ as the output value.

Comment: I don't know for sure what a computable function is, but if it is, among other things, a complex-valued function on the natural numbers, and you want to extend it to an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$, then I think you can. There is a theorem in Chapter 15 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis that guarantees for any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{C}$ with no limit points the existence of an entire function taking prescribed values at each element of $A$ (you can even specify as many derivatives as you want at each point). 

Comment: Keenan, that would seem to answer the question. A computable function on $\mathbb{N}$ is a partial function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ for which there is a computable procedure (e.g. Turing machine) which on input $n$ gives output $f(n)$. 

Comment: @Keenan Kidwell,I think you have answered the question,I will look up Rudin's book,having been embarassed to tell you I have read it many years ago.

Comment:  @Joel David,"In computability theory, c.e. is the usual abbreviation for computably enumerable, which is an adjective applied to sets: a set is computably enumerable if there is a computable procedure to enumerate its elements. The graph of a function is c.e. if and only if the function is computable, since on input n, one waits for (n,k) to appear in the enumeration of the graph and at that point gives k as the output value", yes,I have used c.e.loosely or imprecisely

Comment: This question should have said: given a computable partial function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, is there a *computable* holomorphic extension of it to $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$? That would then actually be an interesting question.

Comment: Andrej, why not ask it? 

Comment: @Andrej,thank you for your editing and your comments .Yes,if the class of the corresponding functions has good properties，we can do research of computable functions more conveniently.In fact I think we can transform research of computable function into complex analysis or complex geometry or maybe algebraic geometry(I know very little about algebraic geometry) in a new way(?)

Comment: @Joel: because I could answer it myself with all probability, if I wandered about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any complex-valued function on $\mathbb{N}$ can be extended to an entire function, so the answer is "yes." This follows from Theorem 15.13 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, which states that for any open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and subset $A$ of $\Omega$ without limit points, there exists a holomorphic function on $\Omega$ taking prescribed values at all the points of $A$.